# load html animation

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can animate (fadeIn or similar) transition of pages loaded? This is my code and links...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function cargarContenido(pagina)
{
    $("#content").load(pagina);
}

function cargarContenidoReloj(pagina)
{
    $("#content").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' class='clock' border='0' />");
    $("#content").load(pagina);
}
</script>
```

Links

```
<ul id="nav">
<li id="nav1" onclick="cargarContenido('estudio.html')">ESTUDIO</li>
<li id="nav2" onclick="cargarContenido('portfolio.html')">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li id="nav3" onclick="cargarContenido('servicios.html')">SERVICIOS</a></li>
<li id="nav4">PRESUPUESTO</li>
<li id="nav5" onclick="cargarContenido('contacto.html')">CONTACTO</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Am8pf/

```
var page = $("<div/>").attr('id','page').load(pagina);
$("#content").html(page).fadeIn('slow');
//^^^^^^^^^------------------------------hide it with css "display:none;"
```

Answer (score 1):

With ajax, you can use `beforeSend` and `success` events to control the user experience:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST', url: pagina,
   beforeSend: function() {
      $("#content").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' class='clock' border='0' />");
   },
   success: function(data) {
      $('#content').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow'); //fadeIn animation for example
   }
});
```

Comment: I want load html inside #content. This code show me estudio.html like new page

<li id="nav1"><a href="estudio.html">ESTUDIO</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

You can add a handler function to load() that executes after it completes:

```
    $("#loader").show();
    $('#content').load(pagina, function() {
        $("#loader").hide();
    });
```